# Catching a fetch error

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, try-catch, fetch

My understanding is that a piece of code throwing error anywhere in callstack can be caught at final catch block. for fetch error, when no internet is available, when I make APIwithoutCatch in callCallAPI, error is not caught. while APIwithCatch catches its own error. All other errors e.g. 404, are caught at both places, wherever I want.

```js
async function APIwithcatch() {
  try {
    var response = await fetch("http://wwww.dfdfdf.com/user.json");
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function APIwithoutcatch() {
  var response = await fetch("http://wwww.dfdfdf.com/user.json");
  return response;
}

function callCallAPI() {
  try {
    // return APIwithcatch();
    return APIwithoutcatch();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
callCallAPI();
```

My assumption that any error should flow down callstack is correct or not?
What is special about net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error?

Comment: ```js 
fetch(url, requestConfig)
      .then(response => handleApiResponse(response, ...args))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
``` This code catch typeError: Failed to fetch, when trying without internet.
```js
try {
      var response = fetch(url, requestConfig)
      return response
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
``` This throw uncaughtPromiseRejection Error.

Comment: "*All other errors e.g. 404, are caught at both places*" - you are not handling status codes anywhere, what makes you think that is an error? (Sure a 404 network request shows up in console separately, but you're not logging it from the code you posted)

Comment: Here is a gist that I created out of code that I am using in my project. It might not work but will give you more details. https://gist.github.com/skant09/e85416c0b7fc26627989dd9f6c292984

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the code in your question. How are you calling `postAPI`, what are you expecting, what does not work when you get which response?

Comment: When I call postApi, and internet is not there, I am unable to catch the error.

Comment: I tested your code down below, ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED is getting caught as 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'. So, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`APIwithoutcatch` is an `async function` - it doesn't throw an exception but rather will reject the promise that it returns. You need to wait for the promise, either with `then` or `await` syntax (just like you did `await` the `fetch` within `APIwithcatch`):

```
async function API() {
  return fetch("http://wwww.example.com/user.json");
}

function callAPI() {
  try {
    await API();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
callAPI();
```

Answer (score 8):

[Per MDN,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) the fetch() API only rejects a promise when a “network error is encountered, although this usually means permissions issues or similar.” Basically fetch() will only reject a promise if the user is offline, or some unlikely networking error occurs, such a DNS lookup failure.

However fetch provides a ok flag that we can use to check if the HTTP status code is a success or not and `throw` a user-defined exception

`await response.json()` will extract the JSON body content from the response so we can `throw` it to the `.catch` block.

```
    async function APIwithcatch() {
      try {
        var response = await fetch("http://wwww.dfdfdf.com/user.json");

        if (!response.ok) throw await response.json();

        return response;

      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD: got your problem, unfortunately you can't catch an error like in your code

Fetch is asynchronous, so you mustn't use `try {} catch {}` construction, use `.then().catch()` instead:

```
async function APIwithoutcatch() {
  var response = await fetch("http://wwww.dfdfdf.com/user.json");
  return response;
}

function callCallAPI() {
  return APIwithoutcatch()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}

callCallAPI();
```

Comment: the problem is only with *net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED* error. When there is no connectivity, promise is able to generate an error but try/catch block isn't. I am just trying to understand what is happening?

Comment: I got your problem so I updated the answer. You may use axios instead of fetch btw, it will solve your problem.

Comment: I understand the solution. I know it. I just want to know why does try/catch with async/await doesn't work in this condition.

Comment: It might be because of difference between error and exception or something related to how Promise.reject works. I just want to know that.

Comment: It didn't work because `try` body in `callCallApi()` returns Promise.
You may also make `callCallApi()` asynchronous and do something like `try { var res = await APIwithoutcatch(); return res; `}